# I'm looking for a simple data storage plugin for Wordpress

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I'm looking for a very simple wordpress plugin and after looking through a couple thousand plugins on the wordpress site, I thought maybe someone here can point me in the right direction.

I need to have a small admin section to save simple key value pairs (strings, or ints), and have the ability to pull those values out with a snippet of code in the template.

This data needs to be available site wide (not custom fields within a post).

It's for a non-profit with no budget, so I'm hoping to not have to write something.  They just need the ability to go into the back end, and update a few fields (number of donations, total value of donations, and the location of the next school they will be visiting), and those values will be outputted into the header and inside the body of a few pages.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much in advance,

B

Comment: You want to edit add update the database right?

Comment: Yes, hopefully via a plugin that already has a page in the admin panel, and then just key=>value pairs.

Comment: You will have to edit some plugin ..integrate few plugins to fulfill your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone wondering: I found this:  http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-website-data/

It works exactly as I needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just for a select set of options and adding options does not need to be dynamic... You should just create a plugin.

Its very basic stuff, options and setting a admin page.

It doesn't get any easier than that for creating a plugin.
You could probably just Google Creating you first WordPress plugin and any of the tutorials will almost give you the exact code you need.